# MongoDB Windows install fails if select specific features with error "The expression after '&'..."

Tags: mongodb, wix

. I am trying to do an automated install of MongoDB Community Edition 3.6.2 on a Window server that is not connected to the Internet.

The problem is the MSI install fails due to the attempted download of the Compass toolset at the end of the process. As I do not need to install Compass I thought I should be able to disable the installation of this feature.

However, when I pass in command line to only install specific MongoDb features, as per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/),

```
 msiexec.exe 
    /qn 
    /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.2-signed.msi
    INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\" 
    ADDLOCAL=Server 
    /l*v MongoDBInstall.log
```

the install fails with the following error (in the MSEXEC error log). the error occurs whenever the **ADDLOCAL** parameter is set to anything other than **ALL**

```
WixQuietExec64:  The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command  WixQuietExec64:  name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object. WixQuietExec64:  At line:1 char:3 
WixQuietExec64:  + & '' ; exit $($Error.Count) WixQuietExec64:  +   ~~ 
WixQuietExec64:      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:String) , RuntimeException WixQuietExec64:      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression 
WixQuietExec64:
WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: Command line returned an error. 
WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: QuietExec64 Failed 
WixQuietExec64:  Error 0x80070001: Failed in ExecCommon method
CustomAction InstallCompassScript returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
```

Anyone seen this before, and have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option for installing that compass in the MSI. By default, it will be selected to install, Deselect that option and try to install.

It will appear after giving the complete install as showing in image below

[image: Mongo Compass Install Option]

Hope this helps.,

Comment: That works if doing an interactive install, but I am trying to do an automated command line install. It seems that by default a command line MSIEXEC install attempts to install Compass, or at least try to download the MSI. Hence the error I am seeing

Comment: @RichardFennell can you tell the total msiexec command you tried to install

Comment: If I run msiexec.exe /q /i c:\bootstrap\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.2-signed.msi INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\"  /l MongoDBInstall.log the MongoDb install completes if there is an Internet connection, but installs Compass after it has download it - so no use to me if I have no Internet connection

Comment: If I use the command from the documentation to only install specific features

msiexec.exe /q /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.2-signed.msi             INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6.2\"             ADDLOCAL="MonitoringTools,ImportExportTools,MiscellaneousTools"

I see the error I initially reported

Comment: @RichardFennell Did you gave the file location correctly. from your comments in the first comment, it is in the bootstrap folder and from your second comment it was not mentioned

Comment: Yes I did give the correct path. I can see from the MSIEXEC log that it ran, gave the & error and exited

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem and examining the log. I found the property `SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS`.

So try this command:

```
msiexec.exe 
    /qn 
    /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.2-signed.msi
    INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\" 
    ADDLOCAL=Server 
    SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS=0
    /l*v MongoDBInstall.log
```